# Can Marathon assign the same randomly selected host_port across instances?

Tags: mesos, marathon

For my containerized application, I want to Marathon to allocate the same host_port for the container's bridge network endpoint for all instances of that application. Specifying the host port runs the risk of resource exhaustion. Not specifying it will cause a random port to be picked for each instance.

I dont mind a randomly picked port so long as it is identical across all instances of my application. Is there a way to request Marathon to pick such a host port for my container endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are really after is service discovery / load balancing. Have a look at the Marathon docs at

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/service-discovery-load-balancing

to get an overview.

Also, see the Docker networking docs at

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html

You can probably either make use of the `hostPort` or the more general `ports` properties.